# compiling .pyw to .exe with py2exe, when i run show me psutils error

Tags: python

**Ok checked! The problem is not py2exe it's a bug of psutils dont work with windows 10!**

I passed of pyw to .exe and included the most important modules. But when i run the first time show me this error:

> LoadLibrary(pythondll) failedNo se puede encontrar el m¾dulo
>   especificado.

After i checked, and tried again and show me psutil error; this only happen in windows 10, in windows 7 worked fine:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "file", line 17, in File
>   "psutil__init__.pyc", line 126, in File "psutil_pswindows.pyc", line
>   15, in File "psutil_psutil_windows.pyc", line 12, in File
>   "psutil_psutil_windows.pyc", line 10, in __load ImportError: DLL load
>   failed: El sistema operativo no puede ejecutar %1.

How i said before, i compiled with py2exe so i use the follow command: python setup.pyw py2exe.
So maybe i think it's because i must to add module in my setup.py but i doubt because it worked fine in windows 7.

setup.pyw:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['example.pyw'])
```

Reason:
The following modules appear to be missing:

> ['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath',
>   'ElementC14N', 'POW', '
>   _psutil_linux', 'enum', 'ordereddict', 'ordereddict.ordereddict', 'psutil._psuti l_bsd', 'psutil._psutil_osx', 'psutil._psutil_posix',
>   'psutil._psutil_sunos']

**Ok checked! The problem is not py2exe it's a bug of psutils dont work with windows 10!**

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: 2.7 version i use